# non-trivial solution for equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A_{m\times n}$ and $B_{n\times m}$. while $B\neq0$ and $A\neq0$.

also, assume that $AB = 0$

Does the homogenic system $Bx = 0$, has a non-trivial solution? if yes, prove it. otherwise give a counterexample.

I couldn't find a counterexample nor find a way to prove it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does $A$ have to do with this problem?

Comment: Anything you know about $n,m$? And why do you mention $A$?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention $AB=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the relation $AB = 0$ follows that there are vectors in the nullspace of $B^T$ ($\ker (B^T)$) different from $0$ (the rows of $A$).

This because $$0^T = (AB)^T = B^T A^T = B^T \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{a}_1 & \dots & \mathbf{a}_m  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{0} & \dots & \mathbf{0}  \end{pmatrix}$$
where $\mathbf{a}_i$ are column vector representing rows of $A$.

Since $$\dim\text{range}(B) + \dim\ker(B^T) = n$$
or $$\text{rk}(B) + \text{null}(B^T) = n$$

$B$ cannot have full rank, so, if $\dim\ker(B^T) < n$, there are infinite solutions. If $\dim\ker(B^T) = n$ there is no solution, but this is possible only if $B^T$ is the null matrix and this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

The following has no nontrivial solutions to Bx=0.

$B=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$ and $A=\left(\begin{matrix}0 &0 &1\\0 &0 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

> Let $A_{m\times n}$ and $B_{n\times m}$ be nonzero matrices such that $AB=0$.  Then,
>
> $$n\leq m\hspace{3mm} \Rightarrow\hspace{3mm} null(B)>0$$

**Proof:**

Observe that $AB=0$ implies that $B^TA^T=0$, and thus we have

$$B^Ta_1=0$$
$$\vdots$$
$$B^Ta_m=0$$

where the $a_1,...,a_m$ are the rows of $A$.

If $n\leq m$ we have
$$0< rank(A)=rank(A^T)\leq null(B^T)\leq null(B)$$

If $m<n$ then $Bx=0$ may or may not have a non-trivial solution depending on $A$ and $B$.  However a sufficient condition for $Bx=0$ to have a non-trivial solution is
$$n-m<rank(A)$$
*(proof left as exercise)*